# Projects using Protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, netty

I'm looking for some projects using Protobuf to use as a reference for implementing complex protocols. Netty examples are preferred but not required.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ uses the protobuf for the underlying KahaDB Message store

Answer (score 1):

The LocalTime example that comes with Netty helped me a lot to understand how to use protobuf, try to learn from it.

Link: [here](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/localtime/package-summary.html)